# How to read data separately with NetworkStream?

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, networkstream

I want to create a simple chat program using by `C#` and socket programming.
Problem is that when I send 3 messages to the server, it does not read it seperately.
Firstly, it reads the first message and then it reads the rest of the data.

But I want to read all messages seperately.
For example when I send from client to server `hello I'm Bill` three times, then I have to read it three times or have to print to screen seperately.

But it reads the sentence 2 times. How can I print all messages separately?

Here is my client `Send` method:

```
private void bSendMessage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //this method sends to "hello i'm Bill" three times to the server.
    byte[] outStream = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(rTBoxSendMessage.Text + "$");
    serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
    serverStream.Flush();

    serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
    serverStream.Flush();

    serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
    serverStream.Flush();          
}
```

And this is my `DoChat` method that reads data:

```
private void DoChat()
{
    byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[8192];
    string dataFromClient = null;                              

    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
            networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0,(int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);

            dataFromClient = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom);                   
            dataFromClient = dataFromClient.Substring(0, dataFromClient.IndexOf("$"));
            //Here is the problem
            //it prints "hello i'm Bill" two times
            //but i was sent three times
            Console.WriteLine(dataFromClient);
            Program.Broadcast(dataFromClient, clNo, true);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("İstemci cikis yapti");
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            clientSocket.Close();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: TCP is a *stream of bytes*. Not messages. If you want messages, it's up to *you* to implement some form of messaging atop TCP (or move to a higher level protocol that does messaging). At the moment, you're completely ignoring the return value from `Read`, which tells you *how many bytes have been received*. It's not in any way guaranteed to match a same number of bytes passed in a single call to `Write` at the other end.

Comment: But i have to use TCP. is there any way to handle all messages seperately by using TCP? Or how can i implement a  some form of messaging a top TCP?

Comment: One common simple way is to send the message length first, then the message. At the receive end, you loop until you've got the four bytes that make up the message length, decode that, declare an appropriately sized buffer for it and then loop again until you've got all of the bytes for the message.